# LaTeX3: Get a token list var via its name

Tags: latex3, token-lists

Assume I have a function that takes a tl var as an argument:

```
\module_myfunc:N \l_module_tlvar_tl
```

But what I have at hand is not the tl var but the name of the tl var:

```
\l_module_tlvarname_tl
```

How do I invoke `\module_myfunc:N` with `\l_module_tlvarname_tl` in LaTeX3?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_module_tlvar_tl
\tl_new:N \l_module_tlvarname_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_module_tlvar_tl { dope }
\tl_set:Nn \l_module_tlvarname_tl { l_module_tlvar_tl }
\cs_new:Npn \module_myfunc:N #1
{
    \cs_to_str:N #1
}
%%  This is what I want.
\module_myfunc:N \l_module_tlvar_tl
%%  This is how I do it in LaTeX2e.
\expandafter\module_myfunc:N\csname\l_module_tlvarname_tl\endcsname
%%  In LaTeX3: Is this the same as what I want?
\tl_new:N \l_module_tlvara_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_module_tlvara_tl { \tl_use:c { \l_module_tlvarname_tl } }
\module_myfunc:N \l_module_tlvara_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that the correct name of tl variables is `\<l/g>_<module>_<name>_tl` with `<l/g>` being `l` for local and `g` for global variables and followed by a second underscore for internal variables, `<module>` being the name of your module, and `<name>` being the actual meaningful name for the variable.

Comment: If you want to access the value of a variable which's name you need to build, you can use the `v` argument type: `\tl_set:Nv \l_cyker_vara_tl { l_cyker_varname_tl }`.

Comment: I know that module name thing but I think it's too heavy for a small example here. In fact `interface3` also uses simple variable names like `\l_mya_tl`. Isn't that more readable?

Comment: no your example is much less readable. In expl3 you can see if a variable is local or global by looking at the begin,  you can see if something is a tl or clist by looking at the end, and  you can see what is a function (by looking for a colon) and how many arguments it has. All this is missing in your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There it is. Does this look good to you now?

Comment: Much better. Sorry if this feels like we're mocking you (that's not our intention), but this standard was chosen for a reason and if you're asking questions your code should follow the standards as good as you know them in order to reduce the amount of "bad" code out there. See it as being a good role model!

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz No problem. Glad not setting a bad example here.

Answer (score 1):

You should conform to the naming scheme. Really, I mean it.

You seem to be wanting something like

```latex
\tl_new:N \l_cyker_vara_tl
\tl_new:N \l_cyker_varb_tl
\tl_new:N \l_cyker_varname_tl

\tl_set:Nn \l_cyker_vara_tl { something }
\tl_set:Nn \l_cyker_varname_tl { vara }

\tl_set:Nv \l_cyker_varb_tl { l_cyker_ \l_cyker_varname_tl _tl }
```

This will set `\l_cyker_varb_tl` to `something`, because the `v` variant first builds a token (using `\csname...\endcsname`), then uses `V`, so you get

```
\tl_set:NV \l_cyker_varb_tl \l_cyker_vara_tl
```

which does the final assignments of *the contents* of `\l_cyker_vara_tl` to `\l_cyker_varb_tl`.

Comment: `\module_myfunc:N \l_module_vara_tl` and `\module_myfunc:N \l_module_varb_tl` are not the same if the function `\module_myfunc:N` contains `\cs_to_str:N`. So the code will fail if the function checks csname.

Comment: And what is the difference between `\tl_set:NV` and `\tl_set_eq:NN` then?

Comment: The tricky thing is how to produce `\l_module_var_tl` on the input stream using `\l_module_varname_tl`, so that that the function takes as input exactly this variable not another variable with the same content.

Comment: @Cyker Not much difference, actually. I can't understand your last comment, sorry.